# Generic implementation for custom method in @NoRepositoryBean repository Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository which can execute generic specifications:

```kotlin
@NoRepositoryBean
interface SomeSpecificationExecutorRepository<T, ID> :
    JpaRepository<T, ID>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>
```

And several target repositories which looks like:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface SomeViewRepository : SomeSpecificationExecutorRepository<SomeViewEntity, Long>
```

Now I want to add a generic

```kotlin
myCustomFindMethod(id: ID, specification: Specification<T>): T?
```

method which makes some search according to provided specification and extends this specification predicate with some id-specific clauses.

The problem is that if I want to add some custom methods to `SomeSpecificationExecutorRepository` via one more interface it's implementation will be also generic one and I couldn't `SomeSpecificationExecutorRepository` there it to reuse `findAll(specification)` methods.

Is there any ideas how can I solve this case and add som methods to this `@NoRepositoryBean` repository which will be available in all repositories that use this one?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can just add extension function like this:

```kotlin
fun <T, ID> SomeSpecificationExecutorRepository<T, ID>.myCustomFindMethod(id: ID, specification: Specification<T>): T? {
    // Your implementation
}
```

And everything will be fine with this